# How to get each Marker objectID when using ClusterManager

Tags: android, google-maps-markers, markerclusterer

Without using the ClusterManager, I use HashMap to put the Marker and ID into the HashMap, and get the ID in the OnMarkClick method and get the data from database. It's works

```
markers.put(addNewMarker(geoPoint), objectId);

private Marker addNewMarker(ParseGeoPoint parseGeoPoint) {
    double latitude = parseGeoPoint.getLatitude();
    double longitude = parseGeoPoint.getLongitude();
    return googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(
            new LatLng(latitude, longitude)));
}

@Override
public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
    String objectId = markers.get(marker);
    if (null == objectId) {
        return false;
    }
    getMemoryBriefInfo(objectId);
    return true;
}
```

But now I need to use the `ClusterManager` to cluster multiple markers into number.

The problems is It seems there is no way to implement this, in the [demo](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils/blob/master/demo%2Fsrc%2Fcom%2Fgoogle%2Fmaps%2Fandroid%2Futils%2Fdemo%2FClusteringDemoActivity.java) of Google, it just add the Items into the Cluster.

There is a `OnMarkerClick` method in the `ClusterManager` class, but I don't how to Override this and set with my own unique ID.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

there is a global solution for you that help to add title, snippet and icon so you can get what you want.

Modify your ClusterItem Object and add 3 variables :

```
public class MyItem implements ClusterItem {

private final LatLng mPosition;
BitmapDescriptor icon;
String title;
String snippet;

public MyItem(BitmapDescriptor ic,Double lat , Double lng,String tit ,String sni)
{
    mPosition = new LatLng(lat,lng);
    icon = ic;
    title = tit;
    snippet = sni;

}
```

And after you create your costume render :

```
public class OwnRendring extends DefaultClusterRenderer<MyItem> {

    public OwnRendring(Context context, GoogleMap map,
                           ClusterManager<MyItem> clusterManager) {
        super(context, map, clusterManager);
    }


    protected void onBeforeClusterItemRendered(MyItem item, MarkerOptions markerOptions) {

        markerOptions.icon(item.getIcon());
        markerOptions.snippet(item.getSnippet());
        markerOptions.title(item.getTitle());
        super.onBeforeClusterItemRendered(item, markerOptions);
    }
}
```

After that just put this line in your SetUpCluster() function before addItems():

```
 mClusterManager.setRenderer(new OwnRendring(getApplicationContext(),mMap,mClusterManager));
```